# Nextjs shows Error: EPERM: operation not permitted whenever I change Image config

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

getting the below error whenever I try to add domain name in my next.config file-

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
    serverComponentsExternalPackages: ["mongoose"],
  },
  image: {
    domains: ['lh3.googleusercontent.com'],
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.experiments = {
      ...config.experiments,
      topLevelAwait: true,
    };
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Error that I'm getting in my terminal-

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'D:\promptopia\.next\trace'
    Emitted 'error' event on WriteStream instance at:
        at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
        at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
    
    Node.js v18.16.1
```

How I'm using Image in my code:

```
import Image from "next/image";
<Image
          src="/assets/images/logo.svg"
          alt="promptopia logo"
          width={30}
          height={30}
 />
```